# Object of class Producto could not be converted to string in

Tags: php, mysql, poo

Estoy intentando insertar un registro haciendo uso de POO con php. Al momento de insertar me sale el siguiente errror: Object of class Producto could not be converted to string in.

```
$target_path="../imagenes/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['archivo1']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo1']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
        $img=basename($_FILES['archivo1']['name']);


        $target_path2="../imagenes/";
        $target_path2 = $target_path2 . basename($_FILES['archivo2']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo2']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
        $img2=basename($_FILES['archivo2']['name']);


        $objPro=new Producto(0, $_REQUEST['nomCof'], $_REQUEST['apeCof'], $_REQUEST['puesto'], $_REQUEST['conferenciaNom'], $_REQUEST['hora'], $_REQUEST['precio'], $_REQUEST['capacidad'], $_REQUEST['estado'], $_REQUEST['detalle'], $img, $img2);

        $metodos=new MetodosAdmin();
        $metodos->grabarConferencia($objPro);
        header('Location:Dashboard.php');
```

Obtengo los datos por POST y se los paso al constructor y despues instancio al metodo grabarConferencia.

```
    public function grabarConferencia(Producto $pro){

    $cnx=new ConexionDB(); //Creamos un objeto con todos los metodos de la clase  ConexionDB
    $cn=$cnx->getConexion();
    $res=$cn->prepare("INSERT into talleresconferencias values(0, $pro->nombreSpeaker, $pro->apellidoSpeaker, $pro->$Puesto, $pro->nombreConferencia, $pro->hora, $pro->precio, $pro->capacidad, $pro->estado, $pro->detalle, $pro->imagen, $pro->imagenCircular)");
    $res->execute();

}
```

Comment: No, el proceso es el siguiente: 1- Obtengo los datos y se los paso al constructor. 2- instancio la clase que contiene a los metodo. 3- llamo al metodo y le paso su objeto respectivo. 4-el metodo hdeberia hacer el insert. 5- con un header mando a la pagina de inicio. en ningún momento intento imprimir algo en pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

El error ocurre porque estás usando `$` para referirte a la propiedad `Precio` del objeto `Producto` en la consulta de inserción.

La voy a poner aquí identada para que se pueda ver mejor:

```
$sql="INSERT into talleresconferencias 
        values(
                    0, 
                    $pro->nombreSpeaker, 
                    $pro->apellidoSpeaker, 
                    $pro->$Puesto,          -- ERROR aquí
                    $pro->nombreConferencia, 
                    $pro->hora, 
                    $pro->precio, 
                    $pro->capacidad, 
                    $pro->estado, 
                    $pro->detalle, 
                    $pro->imagen, 
                    $pro->imagenCircular
                )";
$res=$cn->prepare($sql);
```

Si quitas la `$` el error debería desaparecer:

```
$sql="INSERT into talleresconferencias 
        values(
                    0, 
                    $pro->nombreSpeaker, 
                    $pro->apellidoSpeaker, 
                    $pro->Puesto,
                    $pro->nombreConferencia, 
                    $pro->hora, 
                    $pro->precio, 
                    $pro->capacidad, 
                    $pro->estado, 
                    $pro->detalle, 
                    $pro->imagen, 
                    $pro->imagenCircular
                )";
$res=$cn->prepare($sql);
```

> ### Nota sobre la seguridad
>
> Dado que los datos de `Producto` vienen de fuentes externas, tu código
>   es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Un usuario mal
>   intencionado podría manipular los valores y causar verdaderos estragos
>   no sólo en tu base de datos, sino en tus dispositivos. Considera usar
>   **consultas preparadas** para neutralizar ese riesgo.